# AspNetCore.Docs Demo from MS - Can't get the large file upload demo to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, large-files

I've been scratching my head yesterday and today trying to see the errors of my ways. But I can't seem to get the [AspNetCore.Docs Large File Upload Demo](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp) to work.

Specifically, I can upload  / test using super small files, but bigger files fail. A 23.6 MB (24,787,557 bytes) file is ok.  But if I try a larger file like 414 MB (434,650,754 bytes) it fails with a 500.

When i try the larger file, it never reaches / enters the while loop:

```
   #region snippet_UploadPhysical
    [HttpPost]
    [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPhysical()
    {
        if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("File", 
                $"The request couldn't be processed (Error 1).");
            // Log error

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
            MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType),
            _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
        var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);
        Console.WriteLine(reader);
        var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(section);
        while (section != null)
```

The file size limit i've tried to impose is 2GB.

My web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="Streaming/UploadPhysical">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <!--unit is bytes => 2 GB-->
                    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

This is what my appsettings (and appsettings.Development) looks like:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "StoredFilesPath": "c:\\files",
  "FileSizeLimit": "2147483648"
}
```

I've added .pdf and .mp4 files to the list of allowed file types in the streaming controller.

```
public class StreamingController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;
    private readonly long _fileSizeLimit;
    private readonly ILogger<StreamingController> _logger;
    private readonly string[] _permittedExtensions = { ".txt",".mp4",".docx",".pdf"};
```

For now, I've disabled the logic that checks the file contents.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**

I put a breakpoint on the Console.WriteLine(reader) and then tried to upload the larger file.

This is what I see for the HttpContext.Request object when I debug it in my immediate window:

```
HttpContext.Request
{Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest}
    Body: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream}
    BodyReader: {System.IO.Pipelines.StreamPipeReader}
    ContentLength: 434650949
    ContentType: "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYUlvA8d1NCASzJLc"
    Cookies: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestCookieCollection}
    Form: '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest)HttpContext.Request).Form' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.BadHttpRequestException'
    FormFeature: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature}
    HasFormContentType: true
    Headers: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.RequestHeaders}
    Host: {localhost:12345}
    HttpContext: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext}
    HttpRequestFeature: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>}
    IsHttps: true
    Method: "POST"
    Path: {/Streaming/UploadPhysical}
    PathBase: {}
    Protocol: "HTTP/2.0"
    Query: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.QueryCollection}
    QueryFeature: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.QueryFeature}
    QueryString: {}
    RequestBodyPipeFeature: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.RequestBodyPipeFeature}
    RequestCookiesFeature: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.RequestCookiesFeature}
    RouteValues: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValueDictionary}
    RouteValuesFeature: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.RouteValuesFeature}
    Scheme: "https"
    _context: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext}
    _features: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.FeatureInterfaces>}
```

And then if i also dump the contents of the HttpContext.Request.Body, this is what I see:

```
HttpContext.Request.Body
{Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream}
    CanRead: true
    CanSeek: false
    CanTimeout: false
    CanWrite: false
    Length: '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream)HttpContext.Request.Body).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    Position: '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream)HttpContext.Request.Body).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    ReadTimeout: '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream)HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    WriteTimeout: '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.WrappingStream)HttpContext.Request.Body).WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    _activeReadWriteTask: null
    _asyncActiveSemaphore: null
    _disposed: false
    _inner: {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream}
```

Comment: Is it failing at beginning of transfer or in the middle?  Sound like at the beginning.  So the server is refusing the transfer before it even starts.

Comment: @jdweng yes i think it's pretty soon after.  it reaches the point where it tries to create the "section" and then it dies.  I've captured the results of the HttpContext, which I'll post now.  Please see Edit 1

Comment: See following : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/define-thresholds-on-the-number-of-http-2-settings-parameters-exchanged-over-a-connection-4da05f11-6920-c75c-935f-b1a471e582ea?force_isolation=true#:~:text=The%20HTTP%2F2%20protocol%20doesn,such%20settings%20frames%20are%20exchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

I had to add the following lines in the Startup.cs Configuration() method:

```
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; //2gb
        });
```

Now it works!